# iPhone Creating Different Themes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I just want to make sure this is possible.  Let's say I build three different views in interface builder, and they all have their own unique buttons/layout.  Is it possible to load, one view based on what the user says in the settings.  If so where should this been done.  Any examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure --

```
int userPref = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"theme_pref"];

UIViewController *controller;
if (userPref == kOption1)
    controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"controller1" bundle:nil];
else if (userPref == kOption2)
    controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"controller2" bundle:nil];
```

Replace UIViewController with the name of your class.  Also, that's just one way of retrieving the preference -- use whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to make sure that this is possible.